# git diff surrenders to new blocks having duplicate first or last lines

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I often have these kind of results when using git diff:

```
     /*
  +   * Newly added comment
  +   */
  +
  +
  +  /*
      * Old comment
      */
```

This is technically correct (since the first line did not change) but makes the later commit information hard to understand - especially when this happens with newly inserted functions:

```
  void function(bool param1,
  +    bool param2,
  +    bool param3)
  +{
  +    //Something else happens here
  +}
  +
  +void function(bool param1,
       bool param2)
   {
       //Something happens here
   }
```

Is there any possibility to give git diff a hint that a whole new block has been inserted, in order to receive:

```
  +void function(bool param1,
  +    bool param2,
  +    bool param3)
  +{
  +    //Something else happens here
  +}
  +
  void function(bool param1,
       bool param2)
   {
       //Something happens here
   }
```

Comment: git diff only is interested in calculating the minimal diff since that is stored in the backend. It aims to reduce disk space usage.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that. Ok, so the priorities lie elsewere. But in the mentioned case, the primary objective still holds (since both lines are equal and it is just a matter of design which one of them to include in the diff) - so it would be theoretically possible to have a more user-friendly experience without breaking the original purpose. And it would definitively be needed, since diffs are often read by humans

Comment: @PhilLab The context caries that purpose.

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem, are you sure that the reason for calculating minimal diffs is to reduce disk space usage? As far as I know, Git does not store diffs. The blobs in the .git directory store the full files.

Comment: These minimal diffs are also a pain when changing any type of file that has repetitive sections, such as JSON files with sections that all have the same fields. The diff gets very confusing. So far I have not found a solution to this. One thing that can mitigate the risk of manual error that this causes (for example when resolving merge conflicts) is to install a pre-commit hook that at least checks for valid JSON structure. Similar hooks may exist for other types of files.

Comment: @Dominik: it does not do that proactively no, it does so when you `git gc`: it then only retains the last copy/ies, and stores the old versions as diffs: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/git-internals-how-works-kaushik-rangadurai